# NSTableView with embedded WebViews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstableview, xcode-storyboard

I'm currently trying to render html content into custom NSTableCellViews inside an NSTableView. This is to render emails inside an email thread individually. On selection, the NSTableCellView either expands to show the rendered email, or contracts to hide it. It seems to be working fine with a combination of:

- tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:
- tableView:heightOfRow:
- tableViewSelectionDidChange:

and:

- noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:
- reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:

Each NSTableCellView has a WebView as its child. The rendered content shows up fine until I start scrolling heavily at which point, off-screen WebViews lose their rendered content. If I force a re-render by contracting and expanding the NSTableCellView, the content appears fine.

Is there a delegate method/a way to fix this? Or should I use something other than WebViews to render html inside an NSTableCellView?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles here into the future, the solution I used was to set the NSTableView.usesStaticContents to YES. This prevents makeViewWithIdentifier from recycling cells and hence allows the WebView's to persist in different NSTableCellViews.

This will obviously use more memory, but since there is a definite limit to the maximum number of cells inside an email thread, the increase is within acceptable bounds.